# Is the particle を in をでる comparable to elative case?

Tags: particles, particle-を, linguistics

I remember that Estonian has multiple grammatical cases marking some kind of location. I recently learned that the particle `を` can be used to mean something like "out of" or "from", for an action that involves continuous movement, such as,

> うちをでます。

This reminds me of the [elative case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elative_case), which marks "out of" or "from", e.g. `maja` is the Estonian word for "house", and `majast` means something like "out of the house". Is this case comparable to the function of `を` in the above sentence, or are the concepts too different for this analogy to be useful? The reason I ask is because I suspect I haven't fully grokked this particle usage.

Please could you use furigana for any kanji you write in an answer.

Comment: And if you wanted to, you could call the を in 「公園【こうえん】を散歩【さんぽ】する」 and 「橋【はし】を渡る【わたる】」 **perlative**!  As an aside, the interpretation of the "perlative" を differs depending on whether the verb is telic or not (has a well-defined endpoint).  The first example I gave is atelic, and the second is telic.

Answer (score 1):

“を” is used as “from” only when used with a verb meaning “get out”.
Usually “から” is used for “from”.
Where both can be used, the meanings are different.

> ⚪︎ 家{いえ}を出{で}る
> Get out of home to go somewhere (eg. shopping).
>
> ⚪︎ 家から出る
> Get out of house (not necessarily to go somewhere; eg. to clean your garden).
>
> ⚪︎ バスを降りる
> Get off the bus because you have arrived at your destination.
>
> ⚪︎ バスから降{お}りる
> Get out of the bus (not necessarily because you have arrived at your destination; eg. because the bus is broken).
>
> ⚪︎ 家から行{い}く
>
> × 家を行く

Comment: In your fourth example, is the translation you've provided the meaning, or a possible implicature? Also, it would really help me if you wrote furigana alongside the kanji; I'm a beginning student.

Comment: @LeoKing That is a possible example.